# How to display an existing tree view inside notebook form view in odoo?

Tags: odoo-15

I have a tree view of model X and I want to display it in a form view of model Y
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748791/15879546

```
<field name="xxx" context="{'tree_view_ref': 'your_modual.your_tree_view_id'}"/>
```